# Navigation bar at the bottom of area 51

Tags: feature-request, area-51, user-interface

At the bottom of all Stack Exchange sites, there is a gray area to navigate between Stack Exchange sites. Except on Area 51.

Can you put this bar at the bottom of Area 51?